# Optional using a generic wild card in map and orElseGet

Tags: java, generics

I prepare a little example to replicate what happens in my project. I know how to workaround it, but I am very curious why it doesn't even compile. The problem is in the last return when I am using a generic wild card in the method `public TestElement<?> test()`, exactly the line `return response.map((element) -> mapAux(50L)).orElseGet(()-> orElseGetAux(20));`... I don't know why it doesn't compile. What am I doing wrong? Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class FullTest {
  public static class TestElement<T>{
    public T element;

    public TestElement(T t) {
      element = t;
    }
  }

  public static <U> TestElement<U> createElement(U input) {
    return new TestElement<>(input);
  }

  private TestElement<?> mapAux(Long element){
    return new TestElement<>(element);
  }

  private TestElement<?> orElseGetAux(Integer element){
    return new TestElement<>(element);
  }

  public TestElement<?> test(){
    Optional<Long> response =  Optional.of(5L);
    return response.map((element) -> mapAux(50L)).orElseGet(()-> orElseGetAux(20));
  }
}
```

**Update 1 - Include the error**

I am using Java 8, over the last version of IntelliJ, and the error is this:

> Error:(33, 78) java: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda  expression

```
FullTest.TestElement<capture#1 of ?> cannot be converted to FullTest.TestElement<capture#2> of ?>
```

**Update 2 - A little further and workaround**

The use of wild card is because I need to return `TesElement<>` of different classes and It is the only way that I find out (in the example Long and Integer). I am open to other options...

Here a possible workaround that I prefer avoid (It is an example, I know `isPresent()` always return true) :

```
public TestElement<?> testWorkAround(){
    Optional<Long> response =  Optional.of(5L);
    TestElement<?> testElement;
    if(response.isPresent()){
      testElement = mapAux(response.get());
    }
    else{
      testElement = orElseGetAux(20);
    }
    return testElement;
  }
```

Comment: @rgettman Thank for the feed back. I include the compiler error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do this?

```
public TestElement<?> test(){
  Optional<Long> response =  Optional.of(5L);
  Optional< TestElement<?> > opResult = response.map( (element) -> mapAux(50L) );

  TestElement<?> result = opResult.orElseGet( () -> orElseGetAux(20L) );

  return result;
}
```

Comment: With this snippet I receive the next error: `Error:(35, 68) java: incompatible types: long cannot be converted to java.lang.Integer`

Comment: It must be the way you are calling it. The above code compiles without any issue on my 1.8.0_112 compiler.

Comment: Ok! I think where is the confusion.  I really sorry. See the last modification that I performed several minutes ago. I changed the method `orElseGetAux(Long)` for `orElseGetAux(Integer)`. But when I indicate that the literal is an integer now (erasing L literal), it works wonderful. However I am still confused because in the same line the code does not compile.

Comment: Sure, the `L` tells compiler that  `20` is of `Long` type but `orElseGetAux` takes `Integer` type. Removing the literal make the it an `Integer`.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to specify it explicitly :)

```
public TestElement<?> test() {
   return Optional.of(5L)
       .<TestElement<?>>map(element -> mapAux(50L));
       .orElseGet(() -> orElseGetAux(20L));
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `map` with the lambda `(element) -> mapAux(50L)` returns an `Optional` of what your lambda expression returns, i.e. an `Optional<TestElement<?>>`.  Your call later to `orElseGet` also takes a lambda expression that returns a `TestElement<?>`.

But there is no guarantee that one wildcard matches another wildcard.  Wildcards represent a specific yet unknown type, so the compiler assumes they don't match.  This means you get the compiler errors:

```
The method orElseGet(Supplier<? extends Main.TestElement<capture#1-of ?>>) in the type Optional<Main.TestElement<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (() -> {})
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Main.TestElement<capture#3-of ?> to Main.TestElement<capture#1-of ?>
```

To get this to compile, you should eliminate those wildcards so type inference can do its thing and match.  One of the following:

1. Make your `mapAux` and `orElseGetAux` methods both return `TestElement<Long>`.

   ```
   private TestElement<Long> mapAux(Long element)
   private TestElement<Long> orElseGetAux(Long element)
   ```
2. Or, make those 2 methods generic, so that the `T` going in is the same `T` going out.

   ```
   private <T> TestElement<T> mapAux(T element)
   private <T> TestElement<T> orElseGetAux(T element)
   ```

Comment: thank you for your response, but what happens when it is needed to return TestElement of differents classes in the `.map` and `orElseGet`? I update the question to include this new aspect too.